# How to add values in an array based on indexes such that the array behaves in a circular way

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to add some values in an array, based on a particular variable called control. Suppose the value of control is 2, then i will perform the operation in following way:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
   array[i+control]=value;
}
```

But, i don't want the array to go out of bounds, so i want that in case the index goes out of bounds, the value should come back in front, like a queue. For example, in case my array is of 5 spaces and the value of control is 2 then in case of above loop's last iteration(i=4), array[i+control] should refer to 2nd index.

Does anybody knows how to solve this issue in a simple way? I don't want to implement the array as queue. Is there any other way?

Comment: `if(i+control<array.length){//Go On`??

Answer (score 2):

You could index *modulo array length*.

`i % array.length`  will run from `control` to `array.length-1` and then start at 0 again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array[(i+control)%(array.length)] = value
```

Doing `n%m` will always return a value in the range [0,n-1] for m less than or equal to n and n for m greater than n (assuming m and n are positive integers).